# Why do I get “Lexical with name '$x' does not exist in this frame” when using “will leave”?

Tags: raku

I have the following Raku code:

```
class Thing {
    method close {
        say "closed";
    }
};

for 1..1000 {
    my $x will leave { .close } = Thing.new;
}
```

Running it, I get the error:

```
Lexical with name '$x' does not exist in this frame
  in block <unit> at c.raku line 7
```

Interestingly, this only happens if the number of iterations is high enough (with 500 or 100, I do not get any error messages).

If I change the body of the cycle to

```
my $x = Thing.new;
LEAVE $x.close;
```

then everything works without errors as well.

What is happening here? Did I misunderstand the `will leave` construct? (It seems to me the two versions should be equivalent.)

EDIT: Further observation – when running the code multiple times, the error appears nondeterministically. This suggests that the problem is somehow connected to garbage collection, but I am still confused as to what actually happens here.

I am using Rakudo v2021.03.

Comment: Thank you for your report.  FWIW, I cannot reproduce this on Rakudo 2021.05.  Could you try this code in that version and tell us the result?

Comment: I have tried running the same code using Rakudo 2021.05. The original code works fine, but if I increase the number of iterations to 10000, the error reappears. If I change the body of the `close` method to `say "closed ", $++;` I observe the error happening nondeterministically somewhere around 1500 to 2000 iterations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bug.  Have made an issue for it: https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/4403

I suggest using the workaround in the meantime.